# Detect click on text part of a block element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html element:

```
<h1>Some text</h1>
```

I need to detect a click and recognize whether it landed on the text part or the blank part of the element.

To preserve consistency of the rest of the app I cannot change the display of this element to `inline` or `inline-block`.

I also cannot modify the inner html of this element so splitting it into two `<span>` elements is not an option either.

The text inside this element is not constant and is in fact editable.

Can I detect a click only on the visible (text) part of this heading?

Comment: what exactly onclicked should be? @akshaykishore

Comment: Try searching on google, attach javascript + your title. you will see lots of results. Come back with your code.

Comment: Can you be more specific @colin renaud? I have shown the html of interest, I don't think the rest of the code is relevant.

Comment: Adding a click event to your `<h1>` tag will only fire when the header (text) is clicked.

Comment: @dvo no it will fire whenever I click anywhere on that line as the `<h1>` tag is a block element and takes up the entire width of the page.

Comment: @CrispJam Not using the tag in your question. That is why we need your code... Nothing in your question says it goes all the way across the page.

Answer (score 1):

*QUESTION* "I also cannot modify the inner html of this element so splitting it into two  elements is not an option either." does this mean after the fact or before the fact? i.e is it that you cannot alter the HTML or that you can't go in and mutate the HTML via JS ?

Current Solution:
I parse all elements with the `.clickable` identifier, remove & rebuild their text contents and place spans around them - this way i can add click listeners to the individual text/span elements - giving me access to the text itself.

```js
const clickables = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable')
clickables.forEach(el => new Clickable(el))

function Clickable (el) {
  const _handleClick = ({target}) => console.log(target.innerHTML)
  const texts = el.textContent.split(/\s/)
  
  el.innerHTML = ''
  
  texts.forEach(t => {
    const span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerHTML = `${t} `
    span.addEventListener('click', _handleClick)
    el.appendChild(span)
  })
}
```

```html
<h1 class="clickable">Some text</h1>

<h2 class="clickable">Some! more! text2</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the use of Jquery you can use the `.click` function to know if the `h1` tag is clicked.

```js
$('#test').click(function(){
    alert("Clicked!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id='test'>TEST</h1>
```

Comment: This still allows the user to click off of the text and in the white-space. They need it to only recognize the click on the text.