# Detect if I clicked on a certain part of text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

I'm using Unity to create an Android/IOS application.

In a page containing a paragraph, I want to know if I click on the last sentence of the text. ("Click here for more details" for example).
After clicking on this sentence I want to open a new page.

I know I can put 2 text elements and add this sentence to the second element and the reset to the first element and add onClick event on the second element.

This is a solution for the problem, but in my case, it can't solve the problem because I am getting text dynamically and its size will change from time to time, so the second text element will not start on the same line after the first element ends.

I need a solution that is done in code.

I saw the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56131773/detect-click-on-text-part-of-a-block-element) but it is for HTML and JavaScript, not for Unity.

I will post one of the answer's code snippet which has the same behaviour of what I want.

```js
const clickables = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable')
clickables.forEach(el => new Clickable(el))

function Clickable (el) {
  const _handleClick = ({target}) => console.log(target.innerHTML)
  const texts = el.textContent.split(/\s/)
  
  el.innerHTML = ''
  
  texts.forEach(t => {
    const span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerHTML = `${t} `
    span.addEventListener('click', _handleClick)
    el.appendChild(span)
  })
}
```

```html
<h1 class="clickable">Some text</h1>

<h2 class="clickable">Some! more! text2</h1>
```

Comment: Achievable with [TextMeshPro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xm6rVhFqTVU)

Comment: @derHugo apparently there are multiple meshes now for each of the material `textInfo.meshInfo[textInfo.characterInfo[currentCharacter].materialReferenceIndex].vertices`.

Comment: @Iggy yeah just noted that it doesn't matter anyway .. not needed for just getting the hovered word

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible using the [TextMeshPro](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@2.0/manual/index.html) or [TextMeshProUGUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@latest/manual/index.html) intstead of `Text`. Then you can do a lot of fancy stuff using the [`TMP_TextUtilities`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xm6rVhFqTVU).

Actually there are a lot more very good reasons why it is worth to switch over to using TMP instead of `Text` - so far I haven't found any good one for preferring `Text` over TMP.

The linked [`TMP_TextUtilities` tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xm6rVhFqTVU)  shows a lot more fancy use cases.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text text;

    public string LastClickedWord;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            var wordIndex = TMP_TextUtilities.FindIntersectingWord(text, Input.mousePosition, null);

            if (wordIndex != -1)
            {
                LastClickedWord = text.textInfo.wordInfo[wordIndex].GetWord();

                Debug.Log("Clicked on " + LastClickedWord);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Simply replace the `Text` component by a `TextMeshProUGUI` component on the object and in your scripts. The usage for setting the `text` is exactly the same.

> I want to know if I click on the last sentence of the text. ("Click here for more details"

Instead of `FindIntersectingWord` you can also use `FindIntersectingLine` and then check the index to only trigger the event for the last one.

```
if(lineIndex == text.lineCount - 1)
```

*Note that lines here means actual displayed lines - not necessarily linebreaks*

Or you could e.g. count and define the amount of words in the last sentence and use

```
if(wordIndex > text.textInfo.wordCount - LastSentenceLength)
```

Or .. you could also directly use a [Link](https://deltadreamgames.com/unity-tmp-hyperlinks) then you can use `FindIntersectingLink` and also check if you hit the last one.

---

Example for a specific character

```
var characterIndex = TMP_TextUtilities.FindIntersectingCharacter(text, Input.mousePosition, null);

if (characterIndex != -1)
{
    var clickedChar = text.textInfo.characterInfo[index].character;
    Debug.Log($"Clicked on {clickedChar}");
}
```

---

**Note:** make sure to pass in the same Camera as used for the `Canvas`. I used `null` because I used a `ScreenSpace-Overlay` canvas without a certain `Camera` referenced. In case you are using e.g. `WorldSpace` you have to

- reference the `Camera` in the `Canvas` → `Event Camera`
- pass the same `Camera` to `FindIntersectingXXX`

Comment: I used Text Mesh Pro UGUI. and I always get charIndex -1

Comment: make sure to pass in the same `Camera` as used for the `Canvas`. I used `null` because I used a `ScreenSpace-Overlay` canvas without a certain `Camera` referenced

Comment: One last question: what if I want to check if I clicked on sentence and not a word. Because maybe one of the words in this sentence is in another sentence

Comment: In this case you'll have to go by index I guess. You could e.g. count the words and use a range of how long the last clickable sentence is. Then you could do `if(wordIndex > text.textInfo.wordInfo.Length - LastSentenceLength - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This video describes a similar concept, only that it detects clicks and hovering over specific characters. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg9WAwd8TKM

To make it work for your idea you can just chack the index of the character that was pressed and then check if it's in certain range from the end of the text.

Hope it helps!